# Finding a pattern in python using re (reggae)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to build a regular expression:

```
mystring = /some/path/with/%variable%/%inside%/%it%/
re.findall("[^\s%]+", allocine_spec[key])
```

And this return the following:

```
['/some/path/', 'variable', '/', 'inside', '/', 'it']
```

But I would like only:

```
['variable', 'inside', 'it']
```

Is that possible using only re?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a much simpler regex:

```
%([^%]+)%
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iP1gV6/1)

This will match a `%`, then capture 1+ chars other than `%` into Group 1 and then will match a trailing `%`. If your strings only contain word characters in between `%`, you may replace `[^%]+` with `\w+`.

Note that `re.findall` returns only the captured substrings if capturing groups are defined in the pattern.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/xDC4c0):

```
import re
mystring = "/some/path/with/%variable%/%inside%/%it%/"
print(re.findall("%([^%]+)%", mystring))
# => ['variable', 'inside', 'it']
```